# Using Mapbox GL JS expressions to set an icon-image

Tags: javascript, expression, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I would like to set an `icon-image` based on a data value (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions).

Also see https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/6935 which has a few examples for how to do this.

I've tried a few things ...

**Using `match`**

```
'icon-image': [
  'match',
  ['get', 'tap_ports'],
  2,
  '{tubes}-circle-15',
  4,
  '{tubes}-square-15',
  8,
  '{tubes}-octagon-15',
  '{tubes}-circle-15' // default
]
```

**Using `case`**

```
'icon-image': [
  'case',
  ['==', ['get', 'tap_ports'], 2],
  '{tubes}-circle-15',
  ['==', ['get', 'tap_ports'], 4],
  '{tubes}-square-15',
  ['==', ['get', 'tap_ports'], 4],
  '{tubes}-octagon-15',
  '{tubes}-circle-15' // default
]
```

**Using `property` and `stops`**

```
'icon-image': {
  property: 'tap_ports',
  type: 'categorical',
  stops: [
    [2, '{tubes}-circle-15'],
    [4, '{tubes}-square-15'],
    [8, '{tubes}-octagon-15']
  ]
}
```

All of those don't produce any icons.

*Also, if I try to log the rendered features from that layer using `queryRenderedFeatures` I see only empty arrays, so the features aren't rendering due to my attempts.*

If I simply set

```
'icon-image': '{tubes}-circle-15'
```

everything renders fine, but only as circles of course.

Comment: Have you tried like: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/8121e9db044533d7e44e0afc8c58e71b6d8ec260/test/integration/render-tests/runtime-styling/layout-property-zoom-expression-to-literal/style.json#L42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestion @ChaseChoi.

When I first tried the `steps` it didn't work either but then I added a debug statement for my layer that was causing problems.

```
map.on('zoom', () => {
  console.log(map.queryRenderedFeatures({ layers: ['tubes'] }))
})
```

In here I noticed that the `layout.image-icon` property was something like `{tubes}-circle-15`, rather than `blue-circle-15`. `{tubes}` should have been a color.

So, staying with the steps approach I used the `concat` expression and it worked!

```
'icon-image': [
  'step',
  ['get', 'tap_ports'],
  ['concat', ['get', 'tubes'], '-circle-15'], // default
  2,
  ['concat', ['get', 'tubes'], '-circle-15'],
  4,
  ['concat', ['get', 'tubes'], '-square-15'],
  8,
  ['concat', ['get', 'tubes'], '-octagon-15']
]
```

I went back and tried the other approaches, using `concat` this time, and they all work *expect for the "`property` and `stops`" approach*.